# mysqlshow with the number of tables

Tags: mysql

Following command will let me know the names of databases.

$ mysqlshow

But how do I know the number of tables in each database and also the number of empty tables?
for e.g.

db count empty

test 10 5

mydb 122 0

client 34 34

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select count(*) from information_schema.tables if you have priviliges on it.

```
select count(*) from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = <My Schema>
and table_type = 'BASE TABLE';
```

and filter on table_rows column for empty yables:

```
 select count(*) from information_schema.tables
 where table_schema = <My Schema>
 and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
 and table_rows = 0;
```

Comment: You need to add `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE' to where clause for both statements in order to remove views from your count

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  Added it to the queries,

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW DATABASES;
SHOW TABLES FROM --your_db_here--;
SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 FROM --your_table_here--;
```

Answer (score 1):

there is a special database, information_schema which contains meta data about all databases on the mysql server.

```
SELECT `TABLE_NAME`, `TABLE_ROWS` 
FROM `information_schema`.`TABLES` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'NameOfDatabaseYouAreInterestedIn'
AND `TABLE_TYPE` = 'BASE TABLE'
```

TABLE_ROWS is not always completely accurate, you may want to loop through the tables and get a count

Comment: You can remove the TABLE_SCHEMA from the where clause if you want info on all databases

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

To get the tables in a database and then count the rows returned.

You can also do this (though it can be very slow):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'my_database';
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this helps but there is a option to `mysqlshow` to show number of rows per table (`--count`):

```
$mysqlshow --count  *p*
Wildcard: %p%
+-------------+--------+--------------+
|  Databases  | Tables |  Total Rows  |
+-------------+--------+--------------+
| implantacao |     25 |          134 |
| pmsp        |     80 |      8561947 |
| tmp         |      7 |            5 |
+-------------+--------+--------------+
3 rows in set.
```

And if you pass the database name:

```
$mysqlshow --count tmp
Database: tmp
+------------+----------+------------+
|   Tables   | Columns  | Total Rows |
+------------+----------+------------+
| builds     |        2 |          0 |
| gtable     |        2 |          5 |
| patterns   |        9 |          0 |
| products   |        2 |          0 |
| sig_types  |        2 |          0 |
| signatures |        2 |          0 |
| versions   |        2 |          0 |
+------------+----------+------------+
7 rows in set.
```

You can add the tablename and get info about it:

```
$mysqlshow tmp gtable
Database: tmp  Table: gtable
+--------+---------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field  | Type    | Collation         | Null | Key | Default | Extra | Privileges                      | Comment |
+--------+---------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
| symbol | text    | latin1_swedish_ci | YES  |     |         |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
| size   | int(11) |                   | YES  |     |         |       | select,insert,update,references |         |
+--------+---------+-------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

Look at `mysqlshow --help` for more options/information.